# Linq to get items where property matches any values from an int array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm fairly new to Linq but I'm pretty sure this can be done...  I have a simple C# model like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }

    public string itemName { get; set; }

    public int? categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller (this is .NET MVC) I'm using PetaPoco ORM to pull data from a database and bind it to a model.  Ultimately I have some data that is of type `List<ItemViewModel>`.

What I want to do is pass an optional array of `categoryId` integers to the controller and filter the data if the categoryId of any of the items in the data matches any of the categoryId's passed to the controller.

The controller is like this:

```
public List<ItemViewModel> GetData(int?[] categoryIds){

    var data = db.Query<ItemViewModel>("SELECT itemId, itemName, categoryId FROM items;").ToList();

    // So far so good. Getting data as List<ItemViewModel>
    // Now, if there are any categoryIds passed in to the controller, filter the data accordingly:

    if(categoryIds!= null && categoryIds.Any()){
        data = data.Where(x => x.categoryId != null && categoryIds.Contains((int)x.categoryId)).ToList();
    }

    return data
}
```

However, this isn't returning any results from my data-set when I believe it should, so I think it's a problem with the `WHERE` statement in the filter.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working please?

Many thanks.

Comment: What happened when you debugged it? What are the values in your input array for example?

Comment: _"I'm using PetaPoco ORM"_ - well that's your problem right there. Anyway why would you pull all database records and query on the client? Why not do a `WHERE ... IN (...)` query if `categoryIds` isn't null? And what does this code do when you debug it, does `data` contain anything? Also, this isn't your actual code, you can't store the result of `Where()` in a variable of `List<T>`.

Comment: The reason for querying in memory rather than via the SQL statement is because there are lots of different filters due to be passed in. I found generating conditional SQL strings to be very verbose and thought this would be a neater way.  (There won't be a massive amount of data so my decision was partly based on that.)

Comment: @CodeCaster I have simplified the code - it's not my entire application, that's true. I omitted to cast the result of the `.Where` to a list, so that has been amended now.

`data` contains all records, as expected, it's just the filter that's not working.

Comment: @CodeCaster, PetaPoco is part of the CMS project this application is being built inside, so it's sensible to use in this instance. Are you saying that results from a PetaPoco query which are mapped to a strongly typed object are somehow not privy to the same functionality by which Linq normally operates? I'd be interested to hear if using PetaPoco genuinely is the problem or whether that's just conjecture.

Comment: No, I just personally hate that ORM, it was a non-constructive joke. The rest of my comment still stands, create a [mcve]. A `List<T>` is a `List<T>`, this problem is not related to PetaPoco.

Comment: Silly question maybe, but there is no chance you're passing a empty array for the 'categoryIds' array. Obviously the 'categoryIds.Contains((int)x.categoryId)' will return null and hence nothing will be returned .

Comment: Can you show at least, projected data and categoryId array values ?

Comment: When you pass an empty list, do you get a list with the values that you "believe" exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is working fine! I suggest that you perform a closer examination of the results from the database.

Below is a sample code in a test environment that is actually returning filtered data

```
[TestClass]
public class Linq
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void LaunchGetData()
    {
        int?[] ids = { 1, 3, 4, 6, null };
        var result = GetData(ids);
    }

    public List<ItemViewModel> GetDermiData()
    {
        var data = new List<ItemViewModel>();

        //Nullable data sample objects
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new ItemViewModel
            {
                categoryId = null,
                itemId = i + 11,
                itemName = $"Item {i}"
            });
        }

        //Data sample objects with values
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            data.Add(new ItemViewModel
            {
                categoryId = i,
                itemId = i,
                itemName = $"Item {i}"
            });
        }
        return data;
    }

    public List<ItemViewModel> GetData(int?[] categoryIds)
    {
        //I have replaced fetching information from the database with getting dermi data from a function.
        //You may still get your information from the database
        //var data = db.Query<ItemViewModel>("SELECT itemId, itemName, categoryId FROM items;").ToList();
        // So far so good. Getting data as List<ItemViewModel>

        var data = GetDermiData();

        // Now, if there are any categoryIds passed in to the controller, filter the data accordingly:

        if (categoryIds != null && categoryIds.Any())
        {
            data = data.Where(x => x.categoryId != null && categoryIds.Contains((int)x.categoryId)).ToList();
        }

        return data;
    }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }

    public string itemName { get; set; }

    public int? categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inner join in Linq to filter records

C# Fiddle link --> https://dotnetfiddle.net/2FWJD0 (Updated with lambda)

```
var result = (from a in data 
         join b in categoryIds on a.categoryId  equals b
         select a).Distinct();
```

using ... Lambda expression

```
model.Where(i => catIds.Contains(i.categoryId.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. If you think the OP's code wouldn't work, and they need to use different code, explain **why**. Otherwise it'll look like you're just guessing.

Comment: Doing same thing without using lambda expression won't be a solution.