# Find the intersection of List<class> and List<int> in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, intersection

I have list of Class named article, and list of int. I like to do the following step in LINQ

my class is

```
public class Article
{
    public string Content { get; set;}

    public int CategoryID {get; set;}
}
```

my list of article is

```
List<Article> articles = new List<Article>()
{
   new Article() {Content = "test1", CategoryID = 1 },
   new Article() {Content = "test2", CategoryID = 1 },
   new Article() {Content = "test3", CategoryID = 1 },
   new Article() {Content = "test4", CategoryID = 2 },
   new Article() {Content = "test5", CategoryID = 2 },
   new Article() {Content = "test6", CategoryID = 3 },
   new Article() {Content = "test7", CategoryID = 4 },
   new Article() {Content = "test8", CategoryID = 4 },
};
```

my list of int is

```
List<int> filteredCategoriesID = new List<int>() {1,2};
```

I want to create a new article list with articles containing the selected category list.

My code is

```
var newArticleList = articles
  .IntersectBy(filteredCategoriesID, a => a.CategoryID)
  .ToList();
```

the result I expected

```
NewArticleList = 
{
    ( Content = "test1", CategoryID = 1 ),
    ( Content = "test2", CategoryID = 1 ),
    ( Content = "test3", CategoryID = 1 ),
    ( Content = "test4", CategoryID = 2 ),
    ( Content = "test5", CategoryID = 2 ),
}
```

But NewArticleList has just a article object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to get items where property matches any values from an int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927710/linq-to-get-items-where-property-matches-any-values-from-an-int-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *filtering*, i.e. all `articles` from initial collection `Where` `filteredCategoriesID` `Contains` article's `CategoryId`:

```
var newArticleList = articles
  .Where(article => filteredCategoriesID.Contains(article.CategoryId))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: worked exactly right

Answer (score 0):

I recommend first converting your filter list `filteredCategoriesID` to a `HashSet` because the time complexity of `Contains()` on `List` is `O(N)` while it is `O(1)` for `HashSet`. So, what you can do is:

```cs
var filterSet = new HashSet<int>(filteredCategoriesID);

var newArticleList = articles.Where(a => filterSet.Contains(a.CategoryId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

just another way using LINQ

```
var newArticleList = (from a in articles
join cid in filteredCategoriesID on a.CategoryID equals cid
  select a)
  .ToList();
```